# Strange sed output when replacing spaces to comma

Tags: regex, sed

When I add two spaces before `*`,

```
echo "a bc   def" | sed 's/  */,/g'
a,bc,def
```

When I add one space before `*`,

```
echo "a bc   def" | sed 's/ */,/g'
,a,b,c,d,e,f,
```

Could anyone share why, when there is one space, the output different?

Comment: Note that this behaviour is independent of the o/s, so I removed the Linux tag and added the regex tag.

Comment: Sure, thanks @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there's a single blank in the matching regex (`s/ */,/g`), it matches zero or more spaces, which means there's a match before each letter, and before the newline.  When you have two blanks (`s/  */,/g`), it matches a blank followed by zero or more extra blanks, and matches in far fewer places.

Comment: thanks and two space + * means space + zero or more spaces?

Comment: Yes; I was adding that as you typed the comment/question.

Comment: Gnu sed and some others have the `+` quantifier exactly for this reason i.e. meaning one or more of the previous pattern. So `ss*` and `s\+` are equivilent ( or using the `-r` option `s+`) where `s` is a space.

Answer (score 1):

`*` means *zero* or more repetitions.

Your first example forces at least one mandatory space.

Comment: Thanks @Karoly Horvath, I think in my second command, it mean matching zero or more spaces, and replace to comma, do not understand why the output looks like ,a,b,c,d,e,f,. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have in the output `,` where there were matches. That is, there was nothing or some spaces.